# Mysql server shutdown for unknown reason

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm running mysql on top of ubuntu and this day it was shutdown with such error log:

```
2023-01-31T06:01:54.103045Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.32-0buntu0.20.04.1).
2023-01-31T06:02:00.160225Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0buntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-01-31T06:02:07.173688Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 135693
2023-01-31T06:02:07.208198Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-01-31T06:02:07.792336Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-01-31T06:02:08.246929Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-01-31T06:02:08.246971Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-01-31T06:02:08.250122Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-01-31T06:02:08.295237Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-01-31T06:02:08.295302Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.pZHTT7en1l/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2023-01-31T06:02:08.342358Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2023-01-31T06:02:09.831354Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-01-31T06:02:10.866259Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 135824
2023-01-31T06:02:10.879644Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-01-31T06:02:11.255502Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-01-31T06:02:11.624236Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-01-31T06:02:11.624298Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-01-31T06:02:11.628000Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-01-31T06:02:11.665001Z 7 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2023-01-31T06:02:11.666090Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-01-31T06:02:13.202391Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-01-31T06:02:14.908883Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 136038
2023-01-31T06:02:14.923342Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-01-31T06:02:15.401784Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-01-31T06:02:15.740718Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-01-31T06:02:15.740759Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-01-31T06:02:15.774065Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-01-31T06:02:15.774150Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
```

Is there any option/place to understand what was the reason? I have not shut it down manually, so trying to understand what was the reason?

Comment: Check your `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log` for out-of-memory killer events.

Comment: @BillKarwin checked for messages around this timestamp and see only http://pastie.org/p/70x3GWR2ZJV86fxJNSHH2D Nothing about oom

Comment: There are some actions by apparmor in that log. Perhaps mysqld is trying to access files that it is not authorized to do. As an experiment, try disabling apparmor temporarily and see if mysqld is allowed to run. If that is successful, it confirms that apparmor is killing mysqld. Then you need to figure out what paths you can use that won't trigger apparmor.

Answer (score -1):

Aptitude unattended upgrades.

This shows your upgrade configuration:

```
# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

For example mine has this, showing that unattended security updates are enabled:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "Ubuntu jammy-security";
};
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    //
};
```

And this shows the schedule, which, maddeningly enough, has nothing to do with cron:

```
# systemctl cat apt-daily-upgrade.timer

# /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities After=apt-daily.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6:00 RandomizedDelaySec=60m Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```